# Problems loading static files on Django

Tags: django-staticfiles

I have been repeating a Django blog project for a while. I am finishing the project for the fifth now. The project includes very basic html, custom CSS, Bootstrap3, a medium text editor and a little JavaScript. This fifth time doing the project, I am having issues with static files, more specifically, the custom CSS. After a couple hours of debugging, I finally reloaded an older project of the same kind just to make sure I'm not going too crazy and found that my older projects no longer have the custom CSS either?! I downloaded and ran everything under the same virtual environment (conda.)

What am I missing? Has anyone had similar issues to this?

Answer (score 0):

So after repetitively reloading the same project on Chrome, I was told that Chrome will save older CSS files in order to load the files faster. I was told to switch over to a different(private) browser and try that. I switched over to Firefox and loaded the same project. Sure enough the project loaded perfectly.